# Refreshed Pygame window shows Sprite's previous location as a part of the background screen

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, draw, fill

Below I have a fighting game, where once a player has been pushed off the screen the game ends and has the option to restart. My problem is that after the restart takes place, wherever the winner was standing a clone (or stamp, or image, or ghost, or blit) remains permanently (even after multiple rounds/deaths). What do I need to fix so that the background is correctly refilled over the old locations? I've tried adding `screen.fill()` in several places to no avail.

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        self.playing = True


    def new(self):
        # RESET PLAYERS
        self.player1 = Player(self, 2, FLOOR, RED)
        self.player2 = Player(self, 7, FLOOR, BLUE)
        return z.run()

    def run(self):
        # LOOP
        while self.playing:
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()

    def events(self):
        # INPUT
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                    pg.quit()
                    sys.exit()

                # MOVE
                if event.key == pg.K_a:
                    self.player1.move(dx=-1)
                if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                    self.player2.move(dx=1)
        # DIE
        if z.player1.x < 0:
            return z.encore()


    def update(self):
        # CHANGE INTERNAL PLAYER DATA
        self.all_sprites.update()

    def draw(self):
        # CHANGE PLAYER PHENOMENA
        z.screen.fill(BACKGROUND)
        z.all_sprites.draw(z.screen)
        pg.display.flip()

def encore(self):
        # PLAY AGAIN?
        curtain = True
        while curtain:
            z.screen.fill(RED)
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                    return z.new()    

z = Game()
z.new()
```

And here below my Player class:

```
    class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y, color):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = pg.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move(self, dx=0):
        self.x += dx

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x = int(self.x * TILESIZE)
        self.rect.y = int(self.y * TILESIZE)
```

New to programming; hopefully this wasn't overkill to include all of this code; believe it or not this actually took me a long time to reduce it under 100 lines.. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because the `all_sprites` variable is not being reset after each game instance. Because of this, the previous game's sprites are still being drawn, even though they are not connected to a `Player`. This can be solved with the [`Group.empty()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.empty) function, such as:

```
def encore(self):
    # PLAY AGAIN?
    curtain = True
    while curtain:
        z.screen.fill(RED)
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                self.all_sprites.empty()
                return z.new()
```

Additionally, it appears that the `z.screen.fill(RED)` has no effect because the display isn't updated during the loop. This can be solved by adding `pg.display.flip()` after.